# Core Plot- Filling Particular Area between a coordinates with color

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I am plotting a graph in which i want to fill the area under the data line with color.but problem is i want to use different color for different intervals.Consider the following graph in link provided.

[Graph Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWCca.png)

**in above graph How can i fill the area between coordinates (0,0) and (30,30) with green color and rest with red color?**

**Edit:** I was able to solve my problem by using two different CPTScatterPlot.One for Green area and other for red.And i added the following code to plot data source method.

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
{           
        if ([(NSString *)plot.identifier isEqualToString:@"Green"])
        {
            if(index<=30)
            {
        NSString *key = (fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX ? @"x" : @"y");
        num = [[plotData objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:key];

        if ( fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldY ) {
            num = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[num doubleValue]];
        }
            }

        }
    else if([(NSString *)plot.identifier isEqualToString:@"Red"])
    {
        if(index>=30)
        {
        NSString *key = (fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX ? @"x" : @"y");
        num = [[plotData objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:key];

        if ( fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldY ) {
            num = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[num doubleValue]];
        }
        }
    }                                                       
    return num;
}
```

Comment: i think this is possible by shadow of plot, please search more for it in code you will surely get method otherwise i will help.

Comment: Were you able to fill the area under the graph with a color?

Comment: @tipycalFlow yes,i was able to fill it.

Comment: @user1249508 If you were able to solve the problem then post it as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by using two different CPTScatterPlot.One for Green area and other for red.And i added the following  code to plot data source method.

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
{           
        if ([(NSString *)plot.identifier isEqualToString:@"Green"])
        {
            if(index<=30)
            {
        NSString *key = (fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX ? @"x" : @"y");
        num = [[plotData objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:key];

        if ( fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldY ) {
            num = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[num doubleValue]];
        }
            }

        }
    else if([(NSString *)plot.identifier isEqualToString:@"Red"])
    {
        if(index>=30)
        {
        NSString *key = (fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX ? @"x" : @"y");
        num = [[plotData objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:key];

        if ( fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldY ) {
            num = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[num doubleValue]];
        }
        }
    }                                                       
    return num;
}
```